# Generic Method With Bounded Extends Enum Parameter - Cannot Access values() method

Tags: java, generics, enums

I would like to write a generic method that takes a bounded parameter that extends Enum. For example, if I have an Enum as follows:

```
public enum InputFlags{
    ONE (0000001),
    TWO (0000002),
    THREE (00000004);

    public final int value;

    InputFlags(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I can then do the following:

```
for (InputFlags ifg : InputFlags.values()){
            // Do something with ifg
}
```

However if I try to do the above in a generic method whose return parameter is bounded, I cannot access the `values()` method:

```
public static <T extends Enum> T getFlags(int f){
        T.values(); // NOT allowed, even though I have bounded by extending Enum.
}
```

It seems as though I cannot access `values()` in the generic method. Is this a peculiarity of Enums or is there a way round this?

Comment: Seems like you are reinventing [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html).

Answer (score 9):

`values()` is a very strange thing in Java. Look in the documentation for `Enum` - `values()` isn't even there! `values()` is not a method of `Enum` at all. Instead a `static` method called `values()` is implicitly added to every class extending `Enum`. But the `values()` method for one `enum` is different from the `values()` method in another `enum`.

The fact that `T extends Enum` means that if `t` has type `T` you can call *instance* methods from `Enum` on `t`. You can't call `static` methods of `Enum` (and even if you could, `values()` doesn't exist anyway!)

`values()` is only useful when you know the actual `enum` by name. It cannot be used when you only have a type parameter `T`.

The way around this problem is to pass a `Class` object. Like this:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T getFlags(Class<T> clazz, int f){
    T[] array = clazz.getEnumConstants();  // This is how you can get an array.
    Set<T> set = EnumSet.allOf(clazz);     // This is how you can get a Set.     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`values()` is a static method inserted by the compiler in the `InputFlags` class. Thus, it is not possible to use `T.values()`, especially since T is a generic type. However, if you can get the `Class` object of T (usually via `getClass()`, or by passing it to `getFlags(int f, Class<T> clazz)`), you can use `Class#getEnumConstants()` on that object.

Comment: I still can't get my head around why it would not be available as I have bounded the parameter to `Enum`. I suppose I need to contemplate this a while..

Comment: values() is a static method in every subclass of Enum, but not a method in Enum itself. Thus, the compiler can't find the method as a member of Enum. Furthermore, the location of a static method (ie., the class it is a member of) is resolved at compile time, which cannot be done here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a *peculiarity* of `static` methods. There is no way in Java, with generics or otherwise, to define an interface that applies to `static` methods, ie. that a class should/must implement a `static` method.

Also, type erasure (among other things) prevents you from using a type variable `T` as a type name in a `static` method invocation expression.

Comment: If I take out the `static` keyword I still get the same problem.

Comment: @kerry `values` is the `static` method, not your `getFlags`.

Comment: OK I misunderstood you about the `static` keyword. I need to think about your answers as I can't work this out in my own head. In my (simple) view, as I had bounded the parameter in the generic method to enum, then surely all enum methods, static or non-static should be available.

Comment: @Kerry Instance methods, invoked on reference values, sure. Not static methods.

Comment: @Kerry Note that this has nothing to do with enum types. It applies to every reference type.