# Java: How to get Values of an Enum Class from an Generic Type Object instance?

Tags: java, generics, enums

I want to create an Enum editor, which takes an Enum type as its generic.
E is a generic type, but restricted to be an Enum type. How can I get the values of the Enum class from the instance e?

```
public class ComboBoxEnumEditor<E extends Enum<E>>{
    public ComboBoxEnumEditor(E e) {
        // how to get values of E from e?
        // attemp1:
        List values = e.getClass().values();
        // attemp2:
        List values = ((Enum.class)e.getClass()).values();
        // attemp3:
        List values = ((Enum.class)e.getClass()).values();
        // none of the above works... 
    }
}
```

Say I have an Enum

```
public enum Location {
    Default( false, EAttributeLocation.MAIN_TABLE_IF_AVAILABLE ),
    Main( false, EAttributeLocation.MAIN_TABLE ),
    Overflow( false, EAttributeLocation.OVERFLOW_TABLE ),
    Separate( false, EAttributeLocation.SEPARATE_TABLE );
    ......
}
```

I want my ComboBoxEnumEditor be able to do

```
{
   ComboBoxEnumEditor(new Location());
}
```

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for (but I may be mistaken)

```
Enum[] values = e.getClass().getEnumConstants();
```

or as mentioned by [@pbabcdefp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3973077/pbabcdefp) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28907900/1393766) (big +1 for him) if you would like to have `E[]` instead of `Enum[]`

```
E[] values = e.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants();
```

Also based on

> ...which takes an Enum Class as its generic

your argument should probably be `Class<E> clazz` not `E e` itself so you could use it with `ComboBoxEnumEditor(Location.class);`. In that case you could simply use

```
E[] values = clazz.getEnumConstants();
```

Comment: This is how I would do it.  `EnumSet.allOf(enumClass)` can also be useful if you need to perform efficient set operations.

Answer (score 5):

```
E[] arr = e.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for. I wish I could make both of you and Pshemo as answers. but he was a little bit faster.

Comment: `e.getDeclaringClass()` would be nice if OP really intend to use `E e`. But with argument `Class<E> clazz` instead `E[] values = clazz.getEnumConstants();` compiles also fine.

Comment: @Alex No worries, Pshemo's answer is more detailed than mine. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27892675/generic-method-with-bounded-extends-enum-parameter-cannot-access-values-meth/27893065#27893065

Comment: @Pshemo I agree that using `clazz` is better. I should have mentioned it in my answer, so +1 to you. IMHO Java enums are excellent apart from the confusion caused by 3 ways to get constants (`values()`, `getEnumConstants()` and `EnumSet.allOf()`).

Comment: Yes that is true, we are screwed by fact that `Enum` doesn't have (maybe even abstract) `values()` method since it is dynamically added by compiler to each specific enum. It would make our life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer... You can't. Doing this is not valid syntax since you can't instantiate an enum:

```
ComboBoxEnumEditor(new Location());
```

Instead, you need to pass the class of your enum and change your method signature for that, e.g.

```
ComboBoxEnumEditor(Location.class);
```